# How to get the plot region sizes of subplots?

Tags: r, graphics

```
plotrgnsize=function() {
    m = par('mai')
    o = par('omi')
    dev.size()-c(
        sum(m[c(2, 4)] + o[c(2, 4)])
        , sum(m[c(1, 3)] + o[c(1, 3)])
    )
}
```

The above function can return the plot region size when `layout()` is not called. When `layout()` is called, `plotrgnsize()` can not get the plot region size of each subfigure. How to get the subfigure plot region size?

```
layout(
  mat=rbind(
    3
    , 2
    , 1
    )
  , heights=c(3, 2, 1)
  )
```

EDIT: Here is the sequence of commands to demonstrate the output.

```
R> plotrgnsize() # after calling plotrgnsize() once before, then dragged the plot window.
[1] 7.805454 5.767547
# ... then run the layout command shown above.
R> plotrgnsize()
[1] 8.227054 6.393147
R> plot(1:10)
R> plotrgnsize()
[1] 8.227054 6.393147
R> plot(1:10)
R> plotrgnsize()
[1] 8.227054 6.393147
R> plot(1:10)
R> plotrgnsize()
[1] 8.227054 6.393147
```

As you can see `plotrgnsize()` does not change when each subfigure is plotted. So it can not get the plot region size for each subfigure.

Comment: When exactly are you calling your `plotrgnsize` function? Are you calling it only once at the end? After each `plot()` Perhaps you could make it more clear with code we can copy/paste to test with to see what's going on.

Comment: Done. Let me know if there is anything else unclear.